# How to remove white space in an `.R` file using `Rstudio`?

Tags: r

This question might be silly. Sometimes, when I copy code from one file to another, the text is paste like this:

```
            Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$ADelay <- "300"
            Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$SW <- "60"
            Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$ADelay <- "300"
            Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$SW <- "15"
            Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$ADelay <- "300"
            Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$SW <- "1"
```

Sometimes there are a lot of lines in my `.R` file, so I was wondering if there is some shortcut to select the first position of each line at once to delete all the white spaces. I would like to get this:

```
Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$ADelay <- "300"
Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$SW <- "60"
Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$ADelay <- "300"
Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$SW <- "15"
Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$ADelay <- "300"
Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$SW <- "1"
```

Comment: What editor are you using to write your code?

Comment: Hi @sindri_baldur. I use `Rstudio`

Comment: Select your code and press [Shift] + [Tab].

Comment: Do you get this behaviour if you copy it all into a new file?

Comment: My guess is that "sometimes" you have unfinished code (e.g. unmatched `}`) in the file above the position that you pasted. That's why "sometimes" RStudio does this. Might be a good idea to clean the code above.

Comment: To be honest, I don't get very well why it does it. In this case, I was copying code in the same `.R` file (not to another `.R` file), and it introduced those white spaces or `Tab` spaces. I have copied now other lines and pasted them again and I don't get those mentioned spaces. So I don't know very well why and when this occurs, I just know that sometimes it happens to me and I wanted to know a shortcut to select all the code lines a remove that space. What @MartinGal said works perfectly. Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: I will take it into account @Edward, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `styler` package, which also plugs into the RStudio IDE (or works outside of it, your choice): https://style.tidyverse.org/

```r
cat(somecode, "\n")
#             Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$ADelay <- "300"
#             Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$SW <- "60"
#             Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$ADelay <- "300"
#             Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$SW <- "15"
#             Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$ADelay <- "300"
#             Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$SW <- "1" 

styler::style_text(somecode)
# Warning: Could not use colored = TRUE, as the package prettycode is not installed. Please install it if you want to see colored output or see `?print.vertical` for more information.
# Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$ADelay <- "300"
# Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW60$SW <- "60"
# Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$ADelay <- "300"
# Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW15$SW <- "15"
# Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$ADelay <- "300"
# Promedio_short_Pearson_Avg50_SW1$SW <- "1"
```

(Caveat: I don't use it, but linting and styling have come up several times, I thought I'd look into it.)

There are several useful functions within the package, not just on text variables, including: `style_file`, `style_dir`, and `style_pkg`.